# About sdf.hh file and gazebo-deb

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys,
I have difficulty compiling and installing files from the following website: https://github.com/thomas-moulard/gazebo-deb
Can I ask you how i can compile this package correctly please ??
The sdf.hh file is also part of gazebo development.
Thanks,
Have a nice day,
TH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17500/about-sdf.hh-file-and-gazebo-deb/) by [th_Gazebo_](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3943/th_gazebo_/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That looks like a fork of a very old version of Gazebo, are you sure that's what you want to build? You'll have more luck following the instructions here:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [th_Gazebo_](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3943/th_gazebo_/) on 2017-10-14**:
hi there,
thank you very much.
i got it installed from the recommended website.
appreciated a bunch,
have a nice day,
TH